# Link CSS static to Django

Tags: html, css, django

I am pretty new to Django and I do not know how to link CSS to my project.

I have added the static on the settings of the app as below, it works fine when trying to locate a picture on the static folder but it doesn't seem to find the CSS files:

```
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.staticfiles',]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR, ]
```

on my HTML for CSS facing issues:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/mycss.css' %}">
```

if i want to add a picture which is on the same static directory but a different subfolder it works fine as below:

Any ideas what i am doing wrong ? Thank you advance

Comment: Hi, you are in development mode?

Comment: Yes i am in development mode, if i add a picture or something else it works fine and i can see the changes, it only doesnt work for the .css file

Comment: Your css file is inside /static/css/mycss.css in your main project directory? (ie. "static" on the same level as "manage.py")

Comment: yes the static folder is at the same level as the manage.py

Comment: the static project path must be /appname/static/appname/css/mycss.css

Comment: thank you very much it works now !!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in dev mode (DEBUG=True)

```
#In settings.py you need to have
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

#And in your template file:
{% load static %}

#before this line
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/mycss.css' %}">
```

Comment: thank you for your input, that is how i have it structured but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: the static project path must be /appname/static/appname/css/mycss.css